# How does a byte[] in java actually store data

Tags: java

If I have the following:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};
```

I know that the size of each element would be one byte. But what I don't seem to understand is how would the integer `87` be stored in one byte? Or, how does the `byte[]` store data?

**EDIT:** I see that you can store -128 to 127 in a byte here in java. So, does that mean there is no way to store anything greater than or lesser than those numbers in a `byte[]`? If so, doesn't that limit the use of this? Or am not understanding the exact places to use a `byte[]`.

Comment: what is different about `87`? even using _signed_ bytes, you can represent up to `127`

Comment: I don't get your question. `byte` has a range of -128 to 127 in Java so you can easily store the decimal value 87 in it.

Comment: Because Java's `byte` type is signed, 8-bit values between 128 and 255 are represented as negative values between -128 and -1, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A byte is 8 bits.  `2^8` is 256, meaning that 8 bits can store 256 distinct values.  In Java, those values are the numbers in the range -128 to 127, so 87 is a valid byte, as it is in that range.

Similarly, try doing something like `byte x = 200`, and you will see that you get an error, as 200 is *not* a valid byte.

Comment: A `byte` can hold 8-bit values 128-255. It has to be able to, in order to be compatible with other languages that use unsigned bytes instead of signed bytes like Java does. 200 can be represented in a Java `byte` as -56, as both 200 and -56 are represented in 8-bit as `0xC8` hex, `11001000` binary.

Comment: Well, sure, but you can't just directly make such an assignment; you'll have to do some kind of conversion.  It would probably be easier to just subtract `128` from your bytes in the range `0...255` to get them into Java's range of `-128...127`.

Answer (score 2):

A `byte` is just an 8-bit integer value. Which means it can hold any value from -2^7 to 2^7-1, which includes all of the number in {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46}.

An `integer` in java, is just a 4-byte integer, allowing it to hold -2^31 to 2^31 - 1

Comment: I think you mean `2^7` and `2^31`. One bit is reserved for the sign

Comment: And you need to remember that, in Java, `^` means something else, so you need to be careful what you say. :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey: One bit isn't necessarily _reserved_ for sign in two's complement, per se.

Answer (score 0):

A Java byte is a primitive with a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). 87 is within the allowed range. The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters.

A byte[] is an Object which stores a number of these primitives.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is that byte[] stores bytes. The number 87 in your array above it a byte, not an int. If you were to change it to 700 (or anything higher than 127) you'd get a compile error. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `byte` to store values of 8 bit in it which have a (signed) range from from `-128` to `127`.

With `byte[]` you can do some special operations like building `String`s from a given bytestream and decode them with a desired `Charset`, and some functions will give you `byte[]` as their return value.

I don't know enough about the internals of the JVM but it might save memory though.

Answer (score 0):

this is because, the computer stores values in a circular progression. not a linear progression like we learn in mathematics. it is because the memory is not infinite. it is finite. so every data type is storing values as a circular progression. to learn more go to this link and read the article.

https://medium.com/@hmsathyajith/numbering-system-edge-cases-of-java-237377553444