# Creating ByteArray in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a better/shorter way in creating byte array from constant hex than the version below?

```
byteArrayOf(0xA1.toByte(), 0x2E.toByte(), 0x38.toByte(), 0xD4.toByte(), 0x89.toByte(), 0xC3.toByte())
```

I tried to put `0xA1` without `.toByte()` but I receive **syntax error** complaint saying `integer literal does not conform to the expected type Byte`. Putting integer is fine but I prefer in hex form since my source is in hex string. Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

as an option you can create simple function

```
fun byteArrayOfInts(vararg ints: Int) = ByteArray(ints.size) { pos -> ints[pos].toByte() }
```

and use it

```
val arr = byteArrayOfInts(0xA1, 0x2E, 0x38, 0xD4, 0x89, 0xC3)
```

Answer (score 45):

If all your bytes were less than or equal to `0x7F`, you could put them directly:

```
byteArrayOf(0x2E, 0x38)
```

If you need to use bytes greater than `0x7F`, you can use unsigned literals to make a `UByteArray` and then convert it back into a `ByteArray`:

```
ubyteArrayOf(0xA1U, 0x2EU, 0x38U, 0xD4U, 0x89U, 0xC3U).toByteArray()
```

I think it's a lot better than appending `.toByte()` at every element, and there's no need to define a custom function as well.

However, Kotlin's unsigned types are an experimental feature, so you may have some trouble with warnings.

Answer (score 12):

The issue is that bytes in Kotlin are signed, which means they can only represent values in the [-128, 127] range. You can test this by creating a `ByteArray` like this:

```
val limits = byteArrayOf(-0x81, -0x80, -0x79, 0x00, 0x79, 0x80)
```

Only the first and last values will produce an error, because they are out of the valid range by 1.

This is the same behaviour [as in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11747239/4465208), and the solution will probably be to [use a larger number type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266881/4465208) if your values don't fit in a `Byte` (or offset them by 128, etc).

---

Side note: if you print the contents of the array you've created with `toInt` calls, you'll see that your values larger than 127 have flipped over to negative numbers:

```
val bytes = byteArrayOf(0xA1.toByte(), 0x2E.toByte(), 0x38.toByte(), 0xD4.toByte(), 0x89.toByte(), 0xC3.toByte())
println(bytes.joinToString()) // -95, 46, 56, -44, -119, -61
```

Answer (score 7):

I just do:

```
val bytes = listOf(0xa1, 0x2e, 0x38, 0xd4, 0x89, 0xc3)
    .map { it.toByte() }
    .toByteArray()
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to improve upon the accepted solution, I took an inspiration from [here](https://youtu.be/Q0RYVV9rZBI?t=757). Basically, since Kotlin declares its own `Byte` class, we can augment an operator onto its `companion` object, like so:

```kotlin
operator fun Byte.Companion.get(vararg ints: Int) = ByteArray(ints.size) { pos -> ints[pos].toByte() }
```

Then, you can declare a Byte array more "naturally":

```kotlin
val bytes = Byte[0xA1, 0x2E, 0x38, 0xD4, 0x89, 0xC3]
```

Comment: Cute trick, and that would feel quite at home in Ruby. But it doesn't feel very Kotlin-ish.